# How can I enforce an even PDF page count with FlyingSaucer?

Tags: css, pdf, grails, pagination, flying-saucer

I am working on a Grails project that uses the [Flying Saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer) library (via the Rendering plugin) to generate PDFs. I need those PDFs, which can have arbitrary lengths, to be forced to have an even page count. In other words: if the page count comes out odd, I need an empty page to be added to the end.

How can I achieve this? According to the [user guide](https://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_37) it should honour the normal CSS pagination rules, but that doesn't seem to work. I have tried rules like:

```css
body {
    page-break-after: right;
}
```

But they just seem to be ignored. I have tried variations such as `html` instead of `body`, `left` instead of `right` and even `always`.

Is this something this library can do? Perhaps there is some way to more directly tell it to create an even number of pages, not through CSS?

Comment: _"page-break-after: right;"_ - according to MDN, what that does, is _"Force page breaks after the element so that the next page is formatted as a right page."_ - I don't think that means it actually will _create_ a "next page", when there is no more content for one. It would only make the content coming after the element go on a "right page", if that content actually existed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was unable to solve it just with CSS (I think that @CBroe's comment is spot on).

The solution that ended up working for me was pretty hacky: I always add an extra blank page at the end of the document (by adding `<div style="page-break-before: always;">&#0160;</div>` as the last element in the `body`), and then cut off that extra page again if the rendered document ends up having an odd number of pages.

I do the "cutting" by attaching a `PDFCreationListener` that trims the renderer's internal page array to an even size (code is in Kotlin, but can be easily adjusted for other languages):

```
    renderer.listener = object: DefaultPDFCreationListener() {
        override fun preOpen(iTextRenderer: ITextRenderer?) {
            val pages: List<Any?> = renderer.rootBox.layer.pages
            pageCount[0] = pages.size.and(1.inv())
            renderer.rootBox.layer.pages = pages.subList(0, pageCount[0]?:0)
        }
    }
```

I the above code, `renderer` is the `ITextRenderer`, which means that this code is specifically for the `flying-saucer-pdf-itext5` renderer. I'm not sure how this would need to be adjusted for the PDFBox-based renderer.

Comment: The `pageCount[0]` is used to pass the final page count to the enclosing scope (in a `final`/`val` single-element array); feel free to replace by a regular variable